# How to select other checkbox when the last value is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here an example of my checkbox list http://jsfiddle.net/YnM2f/

Let's say I check on `G` then `A,B,C,D,E,F` also automatic checked. How can i achieve my goals with jQuery?

Comment: So you want all of the checkboxes to be checked when you check one of them?

Comment: Or do you want all of the checkboxes above the one you checked to get checked?

Comment: @Dandroid yes, according to the last one.

Comment: If we check on `C` only `A,B` to be checked.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, only 20 months late: [jQuery CheckAll, a plugin I wrote](http://mjball.github.io/jQuery-CheckAll/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will check all checkboxes above a checkboxe that gets checked and uncheck all checkboxes above a checkbox that gets unchecked, given the checkbox layout that you've provided.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var state = $(this).prop('checked');
    var elements;
    if (state) {
        elements = $(this).parent().prevAll();
    } else {
        elements = $(this).parent().nextAll();
    }
    elements.each(function () {
        $('input:checkbox', this).prop('checked',state);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to get all the checkboxes based on which one is clicked.  for this you need to get the parent nodes, siblings that are before it.  Here is some code that will help you get there, but you'll need to work on it to make it work for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/urau8/

```
$("input:checkbox").on("click",function(){
    if(this.checked)
    $(this).parent().prevAll().each(function(){
        $("input:checkbox",this).attr("checked",true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
     var $allParents = $(this).parent();
     $allParents.prevAll().find('input').attr('checked', 'checked');
     $allParents.nextAll().find('input').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

Well it's already been done five times, but this is what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/YnM2f/27/

```
$('input').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $(this).parent('p').prevAll().children('input').attr('checked',true)

         }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YnM2f/16/

It's a very specific solution (as in it will only work with "G"), but it should give you an idea for how to customize this code to meet your needs.

```
$('input:checkbox').filter(function(){
    return (/ G/).test($(this).parent().text())
}).on('change', function() {
    var gBox = $(this);
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(gBox).prop('checked'));
});
```